# Whittaker models and local L-functions.

Tags: number-theory, automorphic-forms

If we have a Whittaker model, how to associate a local L-function to it? Are there some references? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the book of Jacquet and Langlands, where they use Whittaker models to assign $L$-functions to admissible representations of $GL_2$ ? For the book, see [here](http://www.sunsite.ubc.ca/DigitalMathArchive/Langlands/JL.html#book).